# Apply style regardless of content length of button

Tags: wpf, button, styles

I have 2 buttons. say for example a "Browse" button and a "Start Data Backup" Button. I have applied a common style to these buttons. find the buttons below.

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the content of the browse button aligned properly to the center. But the another one doesn't have any borders. it occupied the button completely. I know it is due to the length of the text and we can fix it by setting the width of the button, but unfortunately i cannot set my button width .because i need my button should give same look with different screen resolution.

What i need now is, the content should be aligned as like in browse button regardless of content length. How to achieve this?

Comment: I think you should set the Padding property of the button in the style like this :  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10 0" />

Comment: No padding doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you have limitation on changing the width of Button for different screen resolutions, instead of changing the width of button try overwriting the font size of the content in button. Also make use of content wrapping to get extra text in new line.

Comment: Oh If changing the font doesn't help, may be cut short the content to one word(Backup) and provide details of what it does in tooltip(Start Data Backup).